# Update Status Column in Dataverse

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-webapi, dataverse

Currently, I'm facing a problem with DataVerse. I try to update the pre-defined `statuscode` column through the Web API using C# (and Postman).

I've tried to update with these lines of code

```
{
    "statuscode": 1
}
```

The error is

> 1 is not a valid status code for state code (Entity)State.Inactive on (Entity) with Id.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `statuscode`, you always have to include the according `statecode`. The error message you receive suggest that the current `statecode` and `statuscode` signify an `inactive` state and status (statecode = 1 and statuscode = 2).

To set the record to `active`, try setting the `statecode` to `0`.

```json
{ "statecode" : 0, "statuscode" : 1}
```

Valid statecode and statuscode combinations are varying across Dataverse entities so you need to make sure you pick the correct one for your case.